# celery add_periodic_task not getting registered

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, celery

I am using a very simple program to add a period task to celery beat using `add_periodic_task` as given in the [official example](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#entries)

This is the program `app.py`

```py
from celery import Celery    
app = Celery('tasks', broker='redis://localhost:6379/6')

@app.task
def hello():
    print('hello')


def start_sync():
    app.add_periodic_task(10.0,hello.s())
```

I then run celery worker with beat as follows:

`celery -A app:app worker -B -l info`

Then when I start a python interpreter and do the below but I cant see the task running.

```py
from app import start_sync
start_sync()
```

I have checked the task is registered in celery as when I do `hello.apply_async()` it works

Comment: have you found a solution to this? As I am experiencing the same issue.